# How to make the debugger step through the whole program?

Tags: python, visual-studio

```
import gym
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
env.reset()
for _ in range(100):
    env.render()
    env.step(env.action_space.sample()) # take a random action
```

This is an example from the [OpenAI gym](https://gym.openai.com/docs/). 'Step into' works neither on the `import gym` nor on any of the method calls for `env`, it just skips over them to the next statement. I am new to Python, but not to programming at this point.

In order to build intuition on how exactly `gym` and various Python libraries work I'd like as an exercise to go through them step by step. There is also a plotting issue in all the PyTorch examples and now this one where the window freezes after being run that has something to do with async handling.

Since I'd like to use Python specifically for its interactivity, I want to look into this. How could this be done?

Answer (score 2):

In `Options -> Python -> Debugging` there is a `Enable debugging of the Python standard library` option that needs to be enabled for stepping through the `gym` to work. I am not sure why Python or VS thinks that a random package like `gym` is a part of the standard library.

This applies to VS 2017.